# using longer input_shape to a fixed input_shape model

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have an NLP keras model that accepts `input_shape=(280,)`, but I need to insert a longer variable input size, for example (1110, ), (400,), (350,),... etc
how can I insert such an input without rebuilding/retraining the model again?
I tried to use `numpy.reshape` as `input.reshape((280, ))` but it doesn't work,
any ideas?

Comment: A machine learning model's input and output sizes must be constant.

Comment: You can set `input_shape=(None,)`